# How to view an image full screen on an Apple Watch with no UI showing

Tags: software-recommendation, apple-watch, watchos

I need to be able to display an image (or video) full screen on an Apple Watch, without displaying any UI.

- Opening an image in Photos shows a small watch icon in the bottom
  left corner.
- Opening it from Messages displays the name of the person
  being messaged in the top right corner
- Saving a photo as a watch face
  displays the image with the time over it.

Is there any other way you can think of? It's for a video where a character needs to see a specific image on the watch, and I'd rather not do it in post-production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native way to do this is to use Xcode 12 and a free AppleID to make a custom app using AVKit and SwiftUI.

- https://developer.apple.com/watchos/

Xcode can take your video content and display it as a custom app. QuickTime Player and Xcode can record the screen so you could fake pre-roll Home Screen content and add that to your “actual” video content so you don’t have to tap the screen. You can make a custom icon for your app to mimic whatever you desire. You don’t have to pay for a dev certificate or publish it to the App Store, it will just side load and run on the one watch you use to record your project.

Even though we’re [not really a programming site](https://stackoverflow.com/), here’s two links if you want to research this to either hire someone or start down your development path to realize this:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/building_a_watchos_app
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer